# Making a menu class active when scrolled past

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, scroll

Note: Using Bootstrap

I want to assign a menu item the 'active' class when the anchor is 50px away from top of the screen. This means that i need to unassign the active class in js and assign a new one.

This is my Menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="34">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="main-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="whatbutton"><a href="#whatissm">What We Are</a></li>
                <li id="whybutton"><a href="#whyusesm">Why Us</a></li>
                <li id="offerbutton"><a href="#whatdoessmoffer">What We Offer</a></li>
                <li id="contactbutton"><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Right Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And these are my h1's

```
<h1 id="whatissm" name="whatissm"><span>sometexthere</span></h1>
<h1 id="whyusesm" name="whyusesm"><span>somtexthere</span></h1>
<h1 id="whatdoessmoffer" name="whatdoessmoffer"><span>sometexthere</span></h1>
<h1 id="contactus" name="contactus"><span>Contact Us</span></h1>
```

Now this is where I start to struggle...

from an early post i understand that my js should look something like this

```
<script>
    //smooth scrolling
    $(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        $('[title]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
    });

    $('a').click(function() {
        var reduce = 150;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top - reduce
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    //Making class active by scrolling past it
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        var anchors = $('body').find('.anchor');
        for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
            if (scrollTop > $(anchors[i]).offset().top - 50 && scrollTop < $(anchors[i]).offset().top + $(anchors[i]).height() - 50) {
                $(anchors[i]).addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(anchors[i]).removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

But unfortunately that code isn't working for me. 1) It doesn't unassign the active class 2) it's just not working.

Edit: Similar to this http://getbootstrap.com/css/ (when you scroll the active class in the right menu changes)

Edit2: Added my code for the scroll down active effect... i'm fairly new to js so i may have implemented it wrong somehow.

Comment: Replace #target1, show us your actual code - it's tricky to see how you're selecting the elements you've posted without that.

Comment: will update in a second

Comment: [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/GBbu6/193/)?

Comment: @Pete yes! But when i copied it into my script tag it doesn't work for my site... again, i'm terribly new at js so i kinda need my hand held at this stage :( been trying to fiddle around with your code but can't get it to work...

Comment: ok, so you need change the selectors that are declared at the top to match your html - [see this example with your html structure](http://jsfiddle.net/GBbu6/200/). The section divs represent the container (I'm guessing you have other content with the `h1`s).  If you are just wanting the menu items to highlight and not the h1, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/GBbu6/201/)

Comment: Hey @Pete It's partially working now, its removing the class 'active' immediately though (i used active instead of selected for bootstrap). So it becomes active at a very specific position instead of everywhere less than until a next h1 is found.

Comment: [how's this](http://jsfiddle.net/GBbu6/208/) or [menu highlighting only](http://jsfiddle.net/GBbu6/210/)

Comment: still not working (i'm looking for menu highlighting specifically)

Comment: OH GOD YES!!!!! it totally worked!!!!! thank you so so much!!!!!!!! (changed active-slider to active x_X)

Comment: Okay, okay, after the excitement died down - these are the problems:: is there a way to make 'contact us' active when the page is scrolled right to the bottom? It also doesn't respond to well when scrolling upwards... not sure how to fix this... think it's because of my offset().top - 150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Understood the actual issue:**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
var anchors = $('body').find('h1');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
    if (scrollTop > $(anchors[i]).offset().top - 50 && scrollTop < $(anchors[i]).offset().top + $(anchors[i]).height() - 50) {
        $('nav ul li a[href="#' + $(anchors[i]).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('nav ul li a[href="#' + $(anchors[i]).attr('id') + '"]').removeClass('active');
    }
}
});
```

Same technique; checking if each of your h1 elements are both below the elements top position and above the elements bottom position. If true, get the id of the element and select the corrosponding navigation item and add active class to it.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yrz54fqm/1/

**Old answer**

Following code should give you the result you're looking for

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var anchors = $('body').find('.anchor');

    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
        if (scrollTop > $(anchors[i]).offset().top - 50 && scrollTop < $(anchors[i]).offset().top + $(anchors[i]).height() - 50) {
            $(anchors[i]).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(anchors[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

You need to listen for the scroll event on the window, and check if each of your elements are both below the elements top position and above the elements bottom position.

Replace the `var anchors = $('body').find('.anchor');` on line 3 with whatever the anchor class names are in your situation. Here's a fiddle with HTML and CSS aswell: http://jsfiddle.net/yrz54fqm/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: couldnt get it to work :( editted in my entire js script and hope you can point me to where i'm going wrong.

Comment: You need to add the `anchor`class to your H1's. Don't forget to make an `.active` class in your CSS.

Comment: So sorry! I misunderstood your question in the first place. The answer I made above is highlighting the headers them selves. Doing an edit right now.

Comment: I eagerly await :D so what else do i need to do? add anchor classes or can i take those out?

Comment: Added the edit. Let me know if it helps, should be plug-and-play for you :)

Comment: didn't quite work ... here's a http://jsfiddle.net/33fwsxsj/

not sure why it's not working :/ would really <3 if you could help me out one last time

Comment: I've fiddled with your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/33fwsxsj/3/.

First off, you didn't include jQuery as a library in the Fiddle. Second, you didn't make a class for the active state, thus not being able to see if a change was made to the menu item. I've also made the javascript look at the offset and height of the parent with the content class, instead of the h1 itself, as it's the height of the content that should determine if it's active or not.

Does it make sense?

Comment: cool after including jquery it seems to work :D ... class='active' is part of bootstrap so it should be working on that side :D thanks for all the help! much appreciated!

Comment: This is great code. I'm trying to use it to find certain id elements on the page but it is only working for the first id.  Any idea? The code I changed looks like this: `let anchors = $('body').find( "#intro", "#howtoplay", "#game", "#contact" );`

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * 
 * @param {Element} - element 1 that used to get offset when scrolling
 * @param {Element} - activated when passing element 1 
 * @param {String} - class name to add to element 2 when element 1 is passed
 */
this.ScrollBetween = function(targetElement, pElement, className) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    targetOffsetTop = $(targetElement).offset().top,
    targetHeight = $(targetElement).height();

    (scrollTop > targetOffsetTop - 50 && scrollTop < targetOffsetTop + targetHeight - 50 ? $(pElement).addClass(className) : $(pElement).removeClass(className));
  });
};
```

Made a function so it way easier to understand. Right now it is used in a JQuery Object but can be simply changed to regular function by changing it to

`function ScrollBetween(targetElement, pElement, className){
  .............
}`

**Can be called by**

`ScrollBetween($("#section-1"), $("li-1"), "active");`