# Highlighting item in table of contents when section is active on page as scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight the current section items in a sticky table of contents as you scroll down the page.

The structure is currently like:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2 id="twitter-chats-for-ecommerce">Header</h2>
                <div>content...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the table of contents like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#twitter-chats-for-ecommerce">Twitter Chats for Ecommerce</a></li>
</ul>
```

The anchor is being applied to the header automatically via a Gutenberg block in WordPress (in this case, the h2).

The existing JavaScript for this is the following:

```
(function($) {

    /* Table of contents - highlight active section on scroll */

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            const id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
            if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
            document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`).parentElement.classList.add('active');
            } else {
            document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`).parentElement.classList.remove('active');
            }
        });
        });
    
        // Track all sections that have an `id` applied
        document.querySelectorAll('h2[id]').forEach((section) => {
        observer.observe(section);
        });
        
    });

})( jQuery );
```

But as you can see from the below example screenshot, the item in the table of contents is highlighting when the matching header (in this case h2) is visible on the page.

So in the case where there are multiple headers visible on the page, more than one item is highlighted in the TOC.

[image: Highlight current active items in table of contents as scroll down page]

Ideally, I guess that it should be matching the div of the section but the id anchor is being applied to the header and I don't have control over this.

Is there a way I can modify the JS to somehow only detect the entire div section instead of just the header so that it will only ever have one item highlighted in the TOC - or is there even a better way than this?

An example of one that works perfectly that I'd like to achieve can be seen [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/writing-a-confluence-theme/) (see the 'On This Page' section in right hand sidebar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I modified randomdude's answer to highlight the lowest scrolled-to header. This will persist highlighting of that link until the user scrolls down far enough to another one.

```js
const anchors = $('body').find('h1');

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    
    // highlight the last scrolled-to: set everything inactive first
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
        $('nav ul li a[href="#' + $(anchors[i]).attr('id') + '"]').removeClass('active');
    }
    
    // then iterate backwards, on the first match highlight it and break
    for (var i = anchors.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (scrollTop > $(anchors[i]).offset().top - 75) {
            $('nav ul li a[href="#' + $(anchors[i]).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active');
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

forked fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/tz6yxfk3/

Comment: I resolved this a different way in the end (if I recall rightly, I managed to get the developer of the Gutenberg block to add this functionality to the block) but your fiddle shows this doing exactly as I was after so will mark as the answer - thanks 

Answer (score 6):

This is same answer as above, but is written in pure JavaScript, no need for jQuery. Great work, Crane, works like a champ.

```js
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li > a');

window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  if (typeof(anchors) != 'undefined' && anchors != null && typeof(links) != 'undefined' && links != null) {
    let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    
    // highlight the last scrolled-to: set everything inactive first
    links.forEach((link, index) => {
      link.classList.remove("active");
    });
    
    // then iterate backwards, on the first match highlight it and break
    for (var i = anchors.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (scrollTop > anchors[i].offsetTop - 75) {
        links[i].classList.add('active');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: this code seems to be not completed since both const will be empty if you call script to early, whole code should be surrounded for example by window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {<...>} to ensure that page was loaded

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var anchors = $('body').find('h1');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
        if (scrollTop > $(anchors[i]).offset().top - 50 && scrollTop < $(anchors[i]).offset().top + $(anchors[i]).height() - 50) {
            $('nav ul li a[href="#' + $(anchors[i]).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('nav ul li a[href="#' + $(anchors[i]).attr('id') + '"]').removeClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}

div {
    height: 2000px;
}

div > h1 {
    height: 200px;
}

.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="whatbutton"><a href="#whatissm">What We Are</a></li>
        <li id="whybutton"><a href="#whyusesm">Why Us</a></li>
        <li id="offerbutton"><a href="#whatdoessmoffer">What We Offer</a></li>
        <li id="contactbutton"><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div>
    <h1 id="whatissm" name="whatissm"><span>sometexthere</span></h1>
    <h1 id="whyusesm" name="whyusesm"><span>somtexthere</span></h1>
    <h1 id="whatdoessmoffer" name="whatdoessmoffer"><span>sometexthere</span></h1>
    <h1 id="contactus" name="contactus"><span>Contact Us</span></h1>  
</div>
```

credits: [Making a menu class active when scrolled past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382551/making-a-menu-class-active-when-scrolled-past)

fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/yrz54fqm/1/

Comment: I should add, that the headers could be anything from h1 to h6. But even after changing your h1 to h2 in your js snippet, I tested this and an active class was not being applied to the TOC items at all...

Comment: You can select all 'h' elements like this: ```var anchors = $('body').find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');```

Comment: I managed to get your code working but as far as I can figure, this is is just highlighting the item in the TOC when the header is 50px from top of the screen. As soon as you scroll a fraction more or less, the highlighting vanishes. This is worse than what I had already - the idea is that the item in the TOC remains highlighted whilst the user is reading that section...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/active-menu-scrollspy.html