# Simple Scrollspy without Bootstrap on custom Nav Component

Tags: javascript, dom, bootstrap-5, tableofcontents, intersection-observer

I have a Table of Contents with id `#TableOfContents` in which each `href` points to a h2 or h3.

The problem I am having is that once the Heading, h2 or h3 is observed by intersection observer, Entry for that is *highlighted* by adding class `side-active` for that link in `#TableOfContents`, but as soon as the long content (such as `p` paragraph) after the heading comes in viewport the *highlight* for that section is removed **since the heading is not in viewport.**

This is a problem since I want the section (h2, h3) to still be highlighted until next h2 or h3 doesn't cross half of viewport.

What can I do?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
    const id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        document.querySelector(`#TableOfContents a[href="#${id}"]`).classList.add('side-active');
      } else {
        document.querySelector(`#TableOfContents a[href="#${id}"]`).classList.remove('side-active');
      }
    });
  });

  toc = document.querySelectorAll('#TableOfContents a');
    // get content so that link refer to it
  toc.forEach(function (link) {
    var id = link.getAttribute("href");
    var element = document.querySelector(id);
    observer.observe(element);
  });
});
```

#### Text is highlighted when heading in viewport

[image: Text is highlighted]

##### Text is not highlighted once heading is not in viewport

[image: Text is not highlighted once heading is not in viewport]

Comment: Could you provide the html? Might be easier to help you with that.

Comment: @SimonLeroux You can see some thing like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65954297/highlighting-item-in-table-of-contents-when-section-is-active-on-page-as-scrolli) but that solution is not feasible as it increase h1 heading height. In reality h1/h2 is followed by text and other bunch of stuff.

Comment: Try observing the parent of the heading, which presumably holds all the section's content.

Comment: @AndreNuechter Parent of the heading contains all blob of text h1, h2, h3, p. It wouldn't help as paragraph has nothing to `id` to heading. Only heading and there links in `TableOfContents`

Comment: Then consider semantically marking up your content and wrapping the chapters in `<section>`s. Your intersection logic might need tweaking, but I think your general goal would be served this way.

Comment: @AndreNuechter This can't be done as the content itself is rendered by a static site generator. I need something like [this](retype.com), which looks as if item is connected to a state and only one item in TOC can achieve that state if it has touched top.

Comment: @AndreNuechter Found solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing was we needed to calculate containerBottom by:

1. adding current container's top + next container's top
2. Or if it is last container then,

   current container's top + it's outerHeight()

Once that; if ith container is in scrollposition add class to it **And remove class** from all containers previous to ith container (line no 18-21) (**reverse loop**)

```
$(function () {
  // Table of contents (`ul`) that contains `a` tag in `li` which we want to highlight  
  var sectionIds = $('#TableOfContents a'); 

    $(document).on('scroll', function(){
        sectionIds.each(function(i, e){
            var container = $(this).attr('href');
            var containerOffset = $(container).offset().top; // container's top
            var nextContainer = $(sectionIds[i+1]).attr('href')

            if (i != sectionIds.length-1) {
             // if this container isn't last container
              var containerHeight = $(nextContainer).offset().top;
            } else {
             // last container's height will be outerHeight
              var containerHeight = $(container).outerHeight();
            }
            var containerBottom = containerOffset + containerHeight;

            var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
            if(scrollPosition < containerBottom - 20 && scrollPosition >= containerOffset - 20){
              for (var j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
                $(sectionIds[j]).removeClass('active');
              }  
              $(sectionIds[i]).addClass('active');
            } else{
                $(sectionIds[i]).removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

##### Check the first heading (*"Line Equations"* `h1`) that is highlighted stays highlighted even though the title is not in viewport until next sub heading (*"Distance of a point from a line"*) comes into view.

[image]