# Javascript - How to make a section 'active' when scrolled to

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events, sections

I'm very new to JavaScript so apologies if I'm lacking clarity in any of my description.

I've built a small website that has a java-script generated menu and I'm just wanting to add functionality to highlight a section (and make 'active') in the menu when scrolled to. I've put together the following, which isn't throwing any errors in the console, so I'm unsure what I've missed:

```
const sectionHead = document.querySelectorAll('h2');

const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

// build the nav
function navMenu(){
  for(let section of sectionHead){
      let listItem = document.createElement("li");
      listItem.innerHTML = section.textContent;
      nav.appendChild(listItem);
      listItem.classList.add('menu__link');
      listItem.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        section.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
      });
  };
}
navMenu();

const nav_items = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link')

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let current = "";
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {
      current = section.getAttribute("id");
    }
  });
//set section as active
  nav_items.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("your-active-class");
    section.classList.remove("your-active-class");
    if (section.classList.contains(current)) {
      section.classList.add("your-active-class");
      //console.log (li.classList);
    }
  });
});
```

The 'your-active-class' class has some custom CSS setup so it will just change visibility in the menu.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: The most efficient way to do this (in my opinion) would be an Intersection Observer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Hi Joel,I've had a look through the documentation and I'm not sure I fully understand how to go about implementing it - can you provide an example of how I'd turn my existing code into an intersection observer?

Comment: Check out this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382551/making-a-menu-class-active-when-scrolled-past

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would observe whether a DOM Element is within view, and apply/remove a classname to it. If you look at your inspector, you'll see the 'active' class being added/removed when they enter and exit view.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  //Query objects on document load
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section")
  console.log(`We have ${sections.length} sections`)
  
  // Create options for Observer:
  const options = {
    rootMargin: '100px 0px',
    threshold: [0.25, 0, 0.25, 0]
  }
  
  // Create instance of IO:
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        entry.target.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.remove('active')
      }
    })
  }, options)
  
  // Iterate over each queried el, and add observer:
  sections.forEach(section => { 
    observer.observe(section)
  })
  
  
})
```

```css
section {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 6rem auto;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<section><div>This is the first section</div></section>
<section><div>This is the second</div></section>
<section><div>This is the third</div></section>
```

Comment: Hi Joel,This is close to exactly what i'm wanting, there's only two issues i'm encountering -- this code can set multiple sections to active at one time. Secondly, instead of highlighting the entire section, how can I make a corresponding menu item to this section be highlighted?

Comment: I see. That's a bit different than what I was thinking. The intersection observer can sense *many* instances on the screen at once. You could always evaluate them based on their intersectionRatio, but I'm not sure what your particular use case is looking like. You would choose the descendent element of the active setion, or target the element itself.